# Visual Studio 2015-Debug mouseover With block variables

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

We finally migrated from VS2013 to VS2015.  When debugging, mousing over a variable within a With block doesn't give the popup of the value like it did in VS2013.

Is there some setting that will make it work again?